# css:how to get spaces in between 2 labels on the same line?

Tags: html, css

i am trying to display a few labels with a fair bit of space in between them on the same line in an html document. This does work.
How to get this working in a nicer way?

```
<div>
firstlabel &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp secondlabel

</div>
```

Comment: Hi,

Everything you did looks fine, but you missed semi-colon (;)
&nbsp;

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could wrap your 'labels' in `<span>` tags, give them classes, and add `margin` with CSS.

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/peduarte/Rf5kB/

HTML

```
<div>
    <span class="firstLabel">firstlabel</span>
    <span class="secondLabel">secondlabel</span>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.firstLabel {
    margin-right: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You should use a semicolon after &nbsp.

```
<div>
firstlabel &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; secondlabel
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="left">firstlabel</div>
    <div class="right">secondlabel</div>
</div>

.main{
   width:220px;
    }
.left{
    width:110px;
    float:left;
    text-align:left;
    }
.right{
    width:110px;
    float:right;
    text-align:right;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct non breakable space entity is `&nbsp;`, you forgot the semicolon at the end (;). A better way, however, to achieve what you want to do would be to enclose firstlabel and secondlabel in `<span>` tags and use css to make them stand apart, like suggested by [peduarte](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8518514/671366).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but this is a really freaky way to do that. Why don't you place those Labels in `<p>-Tags` and format the spacing via margin,padding ?

Answer (score 0):

Whether it works depends on the browser; the correct notation is `&nbsp;` with a semicolon (as mentioned by nyarlathotep). But no-break spaces give you very rough control. A better approach is to use CSS, e.g.

```
<div><span style="padding-right: 5em">firstlabel</span>secondlabel</div>
```

You can tune the padding-right value, using whatever units are suitable for your context. But generally, the em unit is most suitable, as it means that the spacing is automatically scaled when font size is changed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised that no one suggested the simple inline style:
`<div style="margin-right: 500px;">firstlabel</div>`

Comment: Opps, the span tag is more appropriate as Jukka suggested, not div

Answer (score -1):

```
<label >Subscription Expiry: 2019=04-30 00:00:00<br><br></label>
```

Subscription Type: paid